# function values are not printing

Tags: python, printing

When I execute this code it doesn't print '`current stack numbers []`' values.

But when I Uncomment the `#s = c()` it works, what is the reason?

```
def c():
    stack = []
    return stack


def check_empty(stack):
    return len(stack) == 0



def push(stack, item): 
    stack.append(item) 
    print("pushed item" + item)


def pop(stack):
    if (check_empty(stack)): 
        return "stack is emtpy"

    return stack.pop()

#s = c()

push(c(), str(1))
push(c(), str(2))
push(c(), str(3))

print("popped item" , pop(c())) 
print("current stack numbers" + str(c()))
```

Comment: `push(c(), str(1))` creates a list which is promptly discarded. Why did you comment out `s = c()`? That is the sort of thing that you need if you want to actually *use* the list. You need a way to refer to the list, which is exactly what assigning it to a variable does for you.

Comment: `c()` returns an empty list every time. "when i Uncomment the #s = c() it works" - is this the only change you do? Because for me results are exactly the same with this line commented/uncommented.

Comment: @John Coleman  Can you please give a simple similar example?  i can't find example on the internet

Comment: @matszwecja you should also change s with c() in other part of calls

Comment: @Mehdi_ "What is #s = c() called in python?"
`#` means anything after that character in that line is a comment and not code;
`=` is an assignment operator, assigning whatever is on the right side as a value of the variable on the left side;
`c()` is a method call of a method named `c` - it takes the arguments you pass to that call (in this case, no arguments), executes the function and returns its value; Since all c() does is create an empty list and return it, `s = c()` is functionally the same as `s = []`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your function `c()` returns an empty list, the last lines of your code becomes

```
push([], str(1))
push([], str(2))
push([], str(3))

print("popped item" , pop([])) 
print("current stack numbers" + str([]))
```

Which will print nothing, as expected.

However, if you set the output from `c()` to a variable and `push/pop` to it, you will get the expected behaviour

```
s = c()

push(s, str(1))  # c = ["1"]
push(s, str(2))  # c = ["1", "2"]
push(s, str(3))  # c = ["1", "2", "3"]

print("popped item" , pop(s))  # prints "popped item3"
print("current stack numbers" + str(s))  # prints "current stack numbers['1', '2']
```

Comment: No problem @Mehdi_. Can you accept my answer?

Comment: sorry i need 15 reputation but it is recorded and will be added soon.

Comment: It's cool @Mehdi_ :)